# Invalid date in Chrome for typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript , please help for the problem below about invalid date in Chrome.

I have a ListViewModel and has code as :

```
module ListView {
    export class ListViewModel{
        public createdDate: Date;
        public name: string;
            constructor(listId:number)   {
                for(var i = 0; i < dataContext.List.length; i++) {

                     if(listId == dataContext.List.id){

                        // PROBLEM IS HERE:
                        this.createdDate = dataContext.Lists[i].createdDate;
                        this.name = dataContext.Lists[i].name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have a controller which to get all list for my view, like

```
module ListController {
    public aList : Array<ListViewModel>;
        export class ListController(){
            aList = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                var newList = new ListViewModel(i);
                aList.push(newList);
            }
        }
    }
```

and dataContext is created manually in run.ts file , like :

```
Lists :  [ 
    new List(1, new Date(2014,1,2), "test1"),
    new List(1, new Date(2014,06,07),"test2")
]
```

and I want to show the list in HTML and i have alread correctly set controller = `ListController` for this page , like :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in aList">
    <label>Name: {{n.name}}</label>
    <label>Date: {{n.createdDate}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is : the list does not display , but in Chrome Console there is no any error.
When debug into `ListModelView`, `this.createdDate = dataContext.Lists[i].createdDate;` is an invalid date, but name is correctly set.

Thanks a lot for having a look.

Comment: Either post the actual code you're running, or post an actual self-contained example. The manually-transcribed version of what you think the minimal example is has a ton of syntax errors and is missing information that is possibly relevant to the problem (e.g. where does `dataContext` come from?)

Comment: Thanks Ryan for response, i have already correct the syntax errors :)- . I do not have real data's at the moment, that is why i created manually dataContext in run.ts for testing. So the code for  two modules are the same in my project , but i only do not post all html file

Comment: For this issue the problem is in html file, i had wrote wrong angular application name, then the outcome is very streng. Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is as follows:

```
var date = new Date(2014,06,07);
```

Your literals `06` and `07` are octals, not decimal numbers.

To create a date, use decimals, like this:

```
var date = new Date(2014, 6, 7);
```

Browsers typically sort this out for you, but the TypeScript compiler will complain about this if you are targeting ECMAScript 5 or above.

If it isn't the compiler warning you are having trouble with, you can revisit your code to solve the simple syntactical issues that TypeScript should also be warning you about (it certainly warned me when I took your examples).

Here is a rudimentary running version, with some bits reverse engineered out of your question. I have given it a quick spin in Chrome and the date is logged correctly.

```
class List {
    constructor(public id: number, public createdDate: Date, public name: string) {

    }
}

var dataContext = {
    Lists :  [ 
        new List(1, new Date(2014,1,2), "test1"),
        new List(1, new Date(2014,6,7),"test2")
    ]
};

module ListView {
    export class ListViewModel {
        public createdDate: Date;
        public name: string;
        constructor(listId:number)   {
            for(var i = 0; i < dataContext.Lists.length; i++) {

                console.log(dataContext.Lists[i].createdDate);

                 if(listId == dataContext.Lists[i].id) {

                    // PROBLEM IS HERE:
                    this.createdDate = dataContext.Lists[i].createdDate;
                    this.name = dataContext.Lists[i].name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


module ListController {
    export var aList : Array<ListView.ListViewModel>;
    export class ListController{
        public aList = [];
        constructor() {
            for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                var newList = new ListView.ListViewModel(i);
                aList.push(newList);
            }
        }
    }
}

var lv = new ListView.ListViewModel(1);
```

The snippet with the compiled JavaScript output is below (albeit I changed it to log to the visible page, rather than the console):

```js
var List = (function () {
    function List(id, createdDate, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.name = name;
    }
    return List;
})();

var dataContext = {
    Lists: [
    new List(1, new Date(2014, 1, 2), "test1"),
    new List(1, new Date(2014, 06, 07), "test2")]
};

var ListView;
(function (ListView) {
    var ListViewModel = (function () {
        function ListViewModel(listId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataContext.Lists.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += dataContext.Lists[i].createdDate + '<br />';

                if (listId == dataContext.Lists[i].id) {
                    // PROBLEM IS HERE:
                    this.createdDate = dataContext.Lists[i].createdDate;
                    this.name = dataContext.Lists[i].name;
                }
            }
        }
        return ListViewModel;
    })();
    ListView.ListViewModel = ListViewModel;
})(ListView || (ListView = {}));

var ListController;
(function (_ListController) {
    _ListController.aList;
    var ListController = (function () {
        function ListController() {
            this.aList = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                var newList = new ListView.ListViewModel(i);
                _ListController.aList.push(newList);
            }
        }
        return ListController;
    })();
    _ListController.ListController = ListController;
})(ListController || (ListController = {}));

var lv = new ListView.ListViewModel(1);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: But 06 and 07 (octal) are equal to 6 and 7. :)

Comment: @Tarh It isn't a JavaScript problem... TypeScript supplies the warning.